# Capture mouse clicks on WPF scrollbar of a TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events

I have a WPF `ScrollingTextBox` defined as follows.
This text box is read-only and its content is updated whenever an event from a ViewModel is fired.

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <local:ScrollingTextBox x:Name="textBox1"
                                Width="480"
                                Height="100"
                                Margin="12,12,0,0"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                IsReadOnly="True"
                                Background="Black"
                                Foreground="White"
                 Text="{Binding Path=UpdatedText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I had to define the following class in order to enable an automatic scrolling-down when new text is added to the text box. Moreover, I needed to override the `OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` and `OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp` methods in order to disable the automatic scrolling-down when the user click on the scrollers: the instructions contained in these methods and the `FindVisualParent` method were obtained from [this page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9a73b1b0-ec76-4b2c-8da6-91c71e3c406f/wpf-mouse-click-event-on-scrollbar-issue).

```
public class ScrollingTextBox : TextBox
{
    private volatile bool _AutomaticScrollingEnabled = true;

    protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInitialized(e);

        VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
    }

    protected override void OnTextChanged(TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnTextChanged(e);

        if (_AutomaticScrollingEnabled)
        {
            Focus();
            CaretIndex = Text.Length;
            ScrollToEnd();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
        object original = e.OriginalSource;

        if (!original.GetType().Equals(typeof(ScrollViewer)))
        {
            if (FindVisualParent<ScrollBar>(original as DependencyObject) != null)
            {
                _AutomaticScrollingEnabled = false;
                Trace.WriteLine("scroll bar is clicked down");
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(e);
        object original = e.OriginalSource;

        if (!original.GetType().Equals(typeof(ScrollViewer)))
        {
            if (FindVisualParent<ScrollBar>(original as DependencyObject) != null)
            {
                _AutomaticScrollingEnabled = true;
                Trace.WriteLine("scroll bar is clicked up");
            }
        }
    }

    private parentItem FindVisualParent<parentItem>(DependencyObject obj) where parentItem : DependencyObject
    {
        DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(obj);
        while (parent != null && !parent.GetType().Equals(typeof(parentItem)))
        {
            parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
        }
        return parent as parentItem;
    }

}
```

1. Why do I need to verify if the event original source is not equal to `typeof(ScrollViewer)`?
2. How does the `FindVisualParent` method work?

Comment: I'm a bit confused ... you wrote this class, yet you're asking how it works?

Comment: @McGarnagle: I wrote the method `FindVisualParent` after reading [this page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9a73b1b0-ec76-4b2c-8da6-91c71e3c406f/wpf-mouse-click-event-on-scrollbar-issue) and I would like to understand how it works ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do I need to verify if the event original source is not equal to typeof(ScrollViewer)?

I gather that the point is to determine where exactly in the `ScrollViewer` the user is clicking.  So, if the ScrollViewer itself is sending the event, that is not useful, and you want to wait until the event tunnels down to one of the specific children you are interested in.  (Note that `PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp` and `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` are tunneling events, which means that the events proceed from the root down through the visual tree until they are handled.)

> How does the FindVisualParent method work?

It just climbs up the visual tree until it either finds an element of the specified type ("parentItem") or it reaches the top.

```
private parentItem FindVisualParent<parentItem>(DependencyObject obj) 
    where parentItem : DependencyObject
{
    // start by getting the parent of the input element
    DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(obj);

    // repeat until there is no parent, or the current element matches the target type
    while (parent != null && !parent.GetType().Equals(typeof(parentItem)))
    {
        // get the next element up
        parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
    }

    // return the found element of type "parentItem", or null if not found
    return parent as parentItem;
}
```